# When I make a box and fill it, it remains unfilled. What should I do?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color

I don't understand why it remains empty when I'm filling it. What mistake am I making?

[image]

Comment: Any appearances on the layer?

Comment: opacity? object on top? clipping mask? effects? what type of box is this?

Comment: Show the layers and appearance panels.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a **wild guess**....

## Turn off `Simulate Colored Paper` in the Document Setup.

When you turn on the `Simulate Colored Paper` option in Illustrator the artboard becomes *that* color. Because the `White` swatch is **not** an ink, it's actually the **absence** of all ink, you get basically no color.

Think about the simulated stock.. if it's dark burgundy, how do you expect *anything* to be white??? The White swatch operates like it should... placing no ink in those areas. So, you get no color, or actually the stock color.

If you *actually want* white to appear there's only one way.. run an actual white ink on press.
If you are *actually* going to print white ink, you need to use a spot color swatch and that means you need to use some other color to *indicate* where white would be printed.

If you need a colored artboard or to simulate colored stock it is **much easier** and less problematic to draw a rectangle the size of your artboard, fill it with the stock color, then lock the layer and build new layers on top of it. This *will* let the white swatch work again... but if you are printing on colored stock, you should **never** use the white swatch. You should be using the stock's color rather than white.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are using the rectangle tool and not the selection tool.

Comment: The box would disappear when the mouse is released if the Selection Tool was being used.